# replace same shortcut from desktop innosetup

Tags: inno-setup

There is already a shortcut on the desktop with same name but it was installed by a setup by setupfactory( i want to replace it with inno). now when i install using a setup created by innosetup it creates a new icon rather than replacing the current one . i added the [installDelete] section but doesnt work. I just checked the shortcut properties. the diff i found is one shortcut has owner as administrators group and the other one is my user. but both was installed by the same user. would that be the reason? is there any workaround for this? or can i check if a shortcut with same name exists? Thank you

Both are pointing to the same exe in same path.
I m installing in windows 7

Comment: More than ownership will be the path what differs. Check the paths of those shortcuts and include them into your question, please.

Comment: Probably you have one shortcut in `Users\YOUR_PROFILE\Desktop` that would be `{userdesktop}` and second one in `Users\Public\Desktop` that would be `{commondesktop}`

Comment: Sorry, I meant the path of the shortcut, not the path to its target. I mean [`this entry`](http://i.imgur.com/Eem8doU.png) (sorry I'm having only Czech Windows since the vendor of my computer decided to force them to me).

Comment: exactly. that was the problem.. thanks a lot RobeN and TLama. i didnt notice it.

Comment: You're welcome! @RobeN, the answer is now yours ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you should check the location of both shortcuts.

Probably one of them is created in Public Desktop folder (for all users) - `{commondesktop}` and the second is presonalized for Current User Desktop folder - `{userdesktop}`.

A.

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; 
WorkingDir: "{app}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

B.

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; 
WorkingDir: "{app}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

Comment: yes that was the problem. now i made it to use userdesktop for both. thanks again.

Comment: @user1616785, you can also [`upvote the answers`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/179541), just like I did few minutes before on this post ;-)

Comment: @user1616785 Note that the `{userdesktop}` you install on may not be the same as the desktop of the user that run the setup. If it had to elevate to admin from a LUA, then the user will be different.

Comment: ok i get that. thanks for the tip. but as the existing installation is done for the current user only. the same would be fine as of now.

Answer (score 1):

When you are switching between installer frameworks it's generally best to uninstall the old version (via its uninstaller) before installing the new one.  (You can automate this.)

If you don't do this, then it's likely that the user will end up with stray uninstaller files on their drive and more than one Add/Remove Programs entry; both of these are ugly.

(This is a one-time thing -- there's no need to uninstall the older version when changing from one Inno or app version to another, only when changing from non-Inno to Inno or the reverse.)

Comment: Yes normally we do that. but we use an upgrade setup also where uninstaller is not included. so the first uninstaller would work fine as the upgrade setup installed the same files only with latest verions. thanks for the tip

Comment: Until some later version where you added an extra file.  (Usually when you're making an update install with Inno you *do* want it to create uninstall entries for this very reason -- Inno is smart enough to add to an existing uninstall log and entry by default, but of course this only works properly if the original install was done with Inno.)  Personally, I'd still recommend detecting this case and asking the user to use the full installer instead.  I'm not sure about SetupFactory, but I do know that MSI-based installers get grumpy if some other installer replaces their files.